# reading in stored searched tweets in rds format

Tags: r, twitter, tweets, rtweet

I recently used search_fullarchive function in rtweet package to read in a large quantity of tweets (~500,000). Because the file is so large and I needed to transfer the data to another computer, I saved the file to rds format, which appeared to be smaller in size. I used the following function in base R to read in the file:

```
tweet<-readRDS("20201211164534-1.rds")
```

However, instead of a dataset I got the object that's captured in the image below

[a screenshot of View(tweet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11UKZ.png)

```
typeof(tweet)
[1]"list"
```

I opened every node but I cannot find the dataset. Does anyone have an idea if/where I can find the dataset with my tweets in the rds file? Thank you!

Update: Someone asked about the function I used to save the tweet dataset. I did not use a function, but r automatically stored the rds files in my directory when I ran the search_fullarchive function as below:

```
fever.june.1<-search_fullarchive(
  fever,#Search query on which to match/filter tweets
  n = 500000, #Number of tweets to return; it is best to set this number in intervals of 100 for the '30day' API and either 100 (for sandbox) or 500 (for paid) for the 'fullarchive' API. Default is 100.
  fromDate = 202006010000, #Oldest date-time (YYYYMMDDHHMM)
  toDate = 202006302359,#Newest date-time (YYYYMMDDHHMM)
  env_name = "develop",#Name/label of developer environment to use for the search.
  #safedir = "~/Desktop/",#Name of directory to which each response object should be saved.
  parse = TRUE,#Logical indicating whether to convert data into data frame.
  token = token #A token associated with a user-created APP
)
```

Comment: What code did you use to create the RDS in the first place? Did you have an `httr` or `rvest` object? It looks like the tweets are in the `content` but they are just raw encoded.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I didn't use any code to save it. The RDS is automatically saved in my directory but the size of the files seemed right

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that's possible. RDS files aren't typically saved automatically.

Comment: I added the code that I ran to obtain the tweets. I believe it's not every function but maybe this function? Let me know what you thiink

Comment: According to the documentation, that function will return a tibble. The only reference to RDS files in that package are for they "scroller" function for dealing with paged requests. You could try following the advice here to open those temp files https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/388. Though a better practice would be to explicitly save the data you want yourself with something like `saveRDS("fever.june.1", "fever.rds")`

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped a lot and I am clearer about what the issue is